# How to use mounted device for storage

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ubuntu-core

I have installed [Ubuntu Core](https://www.ubuntu.com/core) on [Intel NUC](https://ark.intel.com/products/78577/Intel-NUC-Kit-DE3815TYKHE) which has internal storage of just 4 GB (`/dev/mmcblk0`). I installed some applications but ran out of storage so I added a hardisk (`/dev/sda`) with Intel NUC. I mounted the hardisk to path `/mnt/hdd`.

[image]

Now, when I try to download some applications I get the error of not enough free space. Is there a way to force Ubuntu core to use particular mounted device for storage and installation of new applications?

Comment: Sounds like you want to set up LVM  (Logical Volume Manager) to make Ubuntu use both disks as one. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-lvm-to-manage-storage-devices-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: @Minty Isn't it for Ubuntu server? I am unable to run LVM on Ubuntu core.

Comment: you should still be able to install it, it just doesn't come standard.